# White Screen appear and stuck while running in debug mode from top button, and from command flutter run its log to Observatory listening on

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter. White Screen appear and stuck while running in debug mode from top button, and from command flutter run its log to flutter I/flutter(27557):Observatory listening on ***************

[image: 1]

Comment: please share some more details like error log or your code

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada.     when running the app from the top run button ,in log it showing this.                                                                                                                                                     Launching lib/main.dart on vivo 1951 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
I/flutter (30881): Observatory listening on *******************************                                   and after that its get stuc with the white screen

Comment: it seems your app is getting stuck at default splash screen. Please share some code so that people can help you.

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada its for all default code, even for the default increment code which flutter create,

Comment: @TripurariTiwari  did you find a solution? I m facing this same issue with my Vivo, with every flutter projects, but they run smoothly with other devices!

Comment: This is a universal problem with Vivo device running android 11 now

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue and solved it later by updating my Vivo phone to android 12 and connecting to Android Studio with wireless debug (wireless debug in Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) it worked for me very well.